# OpenCV: Matching closest image for large set of images using divide and conquer

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, classification

Say I have an image A and another set of images C={B(1)...B(n)}.

I want to find the closest matching image to A in C image set.
I found this can be done as explained in the sample "**matching_to_many_images.cpp**"
https://github.com/kipr/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matching_to_many_images.cpp

Now I want to scale this problem when n is large number.
I was hoping to divide the C set info sub-sets , detect the most closest image to A in each sub-set separately  (parallel in different nodes) and finally aggregate all the sets to find the most matching images in the entire C set.

But I found out that , "DMatch" count for each image changes depend on the sub-set its belongs to. Means the count of DMatch is a relative value and not an absolute value.

How to solve this issue using divide and conquerer?

Comment: you can use separate threads for `detectKeypoints` && `computeDescriptors` functions. Say you have 1000 images to train and few query images to predict. First you can split 10 threads and each thread will process 100 images. So, you can parallel process for detecting keypoints  and compute descriptors. Later, you can add these keypoints and descriptor under same list and process `matchDescriptors` in single thread .... for this training it requires all images descriptors at a time.

Comment: thank for the tip. So "matchDescriptors" part cannot be parallaize ? I can run "detectKeypoints" and "computeDescriptors" in multiple nodes and send results to the node which process the last step "matchDescriptors". My question is can single "node" be able to handle results from 20,000 images?

Comment: lets try, I am not sure about the number of images. But it is training process. Once you have trained you can write the `DescriptorMatcher` and on next time when need to query new image just load the `DescriptorMatcher` from saved location and prepare new query descriptior & keypoints and predict. after `descriptorMatcher->add( trainDescriptors );
    descriptorMatcher->train();` you can write the descriptor to file for future use. So, next time do not have to bother about training time

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya: I dont have much experience of BOW, but if your set C contains similar images(like a lot pictures of mobiles), I am pretty sure this is a problem of BOW? But if BOW is not right for you, if you want to search for each image, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30440224/possible-to-store-images-in-elasticsearch/34454566#34454566.

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya: I also tried building FlannIndex using Surf Descriptors of each image(limited to 200 features) and using it to search for 2000 images but its size was already huge(306.5 MB). Since, this project was stopped in between, I never got through completing it to production :(.

Comment: @saurabheights thanks for the tips.Sorry I dont have much knowledge about ElasticSearch.Is it possible to create the FlannIndex (which can scale horizontally) on ElasticSearch ?

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya: My apologies, but I am no expert on ES myself, but it does support scaling. You should try the plugins available for both ES and Solr. FYI: U can try building Flann Index yourself, then search on Xmachine, find top Nresults and their score and finally merge the NX results, sort acc. to matching score(number of features matched/ avg distance of matches). But if u use SOLR/ES this will be  so much better to manage when scaling up/down. P.S.: ES/SOLR r built 4 clustering/matching etcs. Just making them fit for feature vector is difficult and thats where these plugin helps.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure FlannIndex the way Opencv uses, is not supported on ES/Solr, but these frameworks do support plugins, which provide the additional support. Support of math vectors(In Surf, we see 64-length, this is how big descriptors output is). Second, is to remember that there is a cluster of these vectors for each image. Third is searching a vector in the ES/SOLR and finding K close vectors(K>=1) and to which Image it belonged. You also need to keep a Unique Id in ES/SOLR to know which image it belonged to. These are the steps which were implemented by these plugin.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226824/is-it-possible-to-query-elastic-search-with-a-feature-vector